# HTML CSS: Best way to Create Search Bar with Magnify Button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

What is the optimal way to create a Search Bar?

Magnify glass should be within text box at the left, vertical center aligned. I feel like this is a messy way, I am relying on spaces '&nbsp, and magnifying glass is not vertical aligned. Could use top pixel margin, but seems like there is a cleaner way. Just started learning html and css. Not a fan of using pixel measurements and spaces, heard that is not good practice.

```css
.md-form.mt-0{
  display:inline-flex;
  width:500px;
}

.material-icons.mdc-button__icon{
  position:absolute;
  top:7px;
  left: 2px;
 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="md-form mt-0">
  <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon">search</i>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search" aria-label="Search">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on `.md-form.mt-0` style. That will make everything centered align vertically. Now, all you need is `padding-left: 25px` on input style. So it will not overlap.

See the Snippet below:

```css
.md-form.mt-0{
  width:500px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;  
}

.material-icons.mdc-button__icon{
  position:absolute;
}

.mdc-button__icon + input{
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="md-form mt-0">
  <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon">search</i>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Bootstrap's default `.input-group` (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/)

If the bg colour of the inputs bother you, you could adjust it to your needs.

Also, if you wish, you could also try to get rid of the border that separates them, but it's not necessary in my opinion.

**See demo code below**

```css
.input-group .input-group-text {
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* if you wish */
.input-group input.form-control{
  border-left-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
       <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon">search</i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. HTML and CSS only. Magnifying glass is a free to use bootstrap SVG.
Run the code snippet to see the result.

```css
.svgWrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top:21px;
  left:15px;
}

.searchBox{
  text-indent:30px;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:200px
}
```

```html
<html>
      <div class="search">
        <div class="svgWrapper">
          <svg class="bi bi-search" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16"               fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
               <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 011.415 0l3.85                 3.85a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 010-1.415z" clip-                     rule="evenodd"/>
               <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 100-11 5.5 5.5 0                  000 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 11-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0113 0z" clip-                        rule="evenodd"/>
           </svg>
        </div>
      <input class='searchBox'type="search" placeholder="Search the web"results="0" />
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: When you horizontally scroll through your code you see large gaps of white space. Not sure why?

Comment: This is just the way its been pasted. You can unify those gaps

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/3972kghm/5/

```
   .md-form.mt-0{
      display:inline-flex;
      width:500px;
    }
    .md-form.mt-0 input{
      padding-left: 25px;
    }
    .material-icons.mdc-button__icon{
      position:absolute;
      top:7px;
      left: 2px;

    }
```

Comment: this answer is close to mine, I am trying to refrain from pixel measurements

Comment: Please explain your answer and how it solves the OP's issue, including a *complete* code example in your answer, not on a third party site.

Comment: Refrain from pixel measurements, Why? You're in the right track, Just dont use nonbreaking spaces, When it comes to faking these kind of things, pixel measurements is all you can go by.

Comment: hi @WaldirBolanos thanks, didnt know thats the case, thought flex containers and natural spacing, vertical align center, etc, were best way,

Comment: Yes, You can definitely get more fancy with it, but when it comes to padding to push the text aside to make room for the icon, pixel measurements is the way to go because they wont change like a none-breaking space would. Take a look at this example: https://colorlib.com/etc/searchf/colorlib-search-6/ Looks fancy doesnt it? Well the input has a padding of `padding: 10px 32px 10px 70px;` to make room to the left for the icon.